# Appropriate primary key and indices for queries with multiple and-connected where-clause terms [sqlite3]

Tags: performance, sqlite, primary-key

I run costly simulations of which I store the resulting matrix as a `BLOB` in a sqlite3 database. This matrix represents a quantity of a physics system which is simulated at a certain `temperature`, with a certain `boundary_condition` and for a certain matrix size `size`. Furthermore, I always use **either** a `convergence` or `number_of_steps` to terminate my simulation, which I need to store as well. When I require this matrix, I query my database as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM matrices
WHERE temperature = ? AND size = ? AND boundary_condition = ?
AND number_of_steps <= ?
ORDER BY number_of_steps DESC LIMIT 1
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM matrices
WHERE temperature = ? AND size = ? AND boundary_condition = ?
AND convergence >= ?
ORDER BY convergence ASC LIMIT 1
```

Right now, I have **no** primary key or indices. The lookups started becoming a bit slow and, well, I found out I'm doing full table scans each time. I looked around and concluded that a composite primary key of `(temperature, boundary_condition, size)` could be appropriate, and indices on `number_of_steps` and `convergence` would result in a complexity of `k log(N)` dependence, where `N` is the size of the database, and `k` the rows of output.

Is this (close to) optimal? An additional complexity I have is that such a composite primary key will be liable to change. If I suddenly have to include another required parameter in my simulation, I'd have to change the primary key. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These queries still have to read all table rows with matching `(temperature, boundary_condition, size)` values to find the one with the largest/smallest `number_of_steps`/`convergence` value.
You could speed up these particular queries by having two indexes on `(temperature, boundary_condition, size, number_of_steps)` and `(temperature, boundary_condition, size, convergence)`.

Primary key constraints enforce uniqueness and document how table rows are to be identified.
If, at the moment, your only goal is performance, it would be easier to have a separate index, which can be easily dropped and recreated.

Comment: Adding those indices reduced the time for 500 lookups from 12 seconds to 0.2 seconds, thanks!